Does anyone have an idea about the execution power of IBM summit for VQE? I'd appreciate sources of papers as well for supercomputer execution
I'm trying to find the execution power of VQE in super computer and I want to know the factors of execution such as iterations, shots, convergence, etc. Please help me and also, I'd appreciate if provided with any papers as well.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When we execute VQE, we need to run the algorithm and at a point, we need to iterate it till we reach convergence. So, I want to find the amount of power it consumes to iterate the whole algorithm till it reaches convergence. There are a few papers on circuits but I want to know the power consumed only for the iterations part.
